# Matlab: Reprojection error is high as compare to calibrated reprojection error

Tags: matlab, stereo-3d, reprojection-error

I calibrated stereo cameras using Matlab Stereo camera app and mine reprojection error was nearly 0.19 pixels. But when I used same calibrated parameters in finding out 3D coordinates of an object, the reprojection error was on higher side nearly 7-8 pixels. What I'm doing is finding out the center of the object in left and right images say (xl,yl) and (xr,yr) respectively and then used these points to find out reprojection error. What I'm doing wrong? Why reprojection error so high as compare to calibrated reprojection error?

Thanks.